# How to read this JSON

Tags: android, json

```
String json =     
[ 
 {"a":{"aa":"string","ab":"string"} },
 {"b":{"ba":"string","bb":"string"} }
]
```

I am trying to parse this data using JsonObject. 
 When i use this code :

```
JSONStringer Js= new JSONStringer(json);
 Log.d("json", ""+Js);
```

it gives me this : (the first line of json but i want all data)

```
{"a":{"aa":"string","ab":"string"} }
```

How can I read this with Android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a `JsonArray` not a simple `JsonObject`

try this:

```
    JSONArray a = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject row = a.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.d("json", ""+row);
    }
```

Comment: Throws exeption. Value ...json... is type of JSONobject not convertable JSON array. I think it is about serial JSON. I am searching it now.

Comment: What you have posted in definitely a JsonArray. I am not sure what is serial JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this JSON is kind of weird, as it wraps the array objects into one additional object each ("a" and "b"), which will make it hard to parse. It should look like this:

> String json =      [   {"name":"a","aa":"string","ab":"string"}, 
>   {"name":"b","ba":"string","bb":"string"} ]

And then you would parse it like this:

```
JSONArray root = new JSONArray(jsonString); //this is the above string
for(int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++){
    JSONObject current = root.getJSONObject(i);

    //Do the parsing here
}
```